# SQL - How do i get back the result between the 2014-02-20 and 2014-03-20 then for 04,05 etc

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL at the moment:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  courtesy
WHERE DATE
BETWEEN  '2014-02-20 00:00:00'
AND  '2014-03-20 00:00:00'
```

how would i get it to automatically get results between the 20th and the 20th of every month when the month changes?

Thanks

***Edit: i meant between the 20th of feb and the 20th of mar. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean `BETWEEN  '2014-02-20 00:00:00' and '2014-02-20 00:00:00'` or `BETWEEN  '2014-02-20 00:00:00' and '2014-03-20 00:00:00'`?  The former is a rather unnecessary use of `between`.

Comment: Yes, I have just edited it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM courtesy
WHERE day(DATE)=20
```

Comment: so would this apply the result between the 20th of feb and the 20th of march?

Comment: As note:  the most recent edit to the question invalidates this answer -- rather unfair in my opinion.  I would discourage anyone from downvoting it.  You can see the history of the question.

Comment: @user3411353 This won't give result between 20th feb and 20th of march.

Comment: absolutely agree with gordon, my fault completely for not giving enough detail

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this will do it.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  courtesy
WHERE DAY(DATE) = 20
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to subtract 19 days and check for the current month.  If I understand your question correctly, here is one way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  courtesy
WHERE year(DATE - 19) = year(getdate()) and
      month(DATE - 19) = month(getdate())
```

Note:  this assumes that `date` is really stored as a `datetime` (because you are comparing it to a constant with a time component).  You can also use `datediff()`.

I also assume that you don't really mean `between`, because that would count the 20th twice, once in each month.